# Beginner question: Filtering dates to match the date of another model in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

Beginner in Django here, I have been trying to work this out on-and-off for the last few days and have tried reading the docs and googling for solutions, but to no avail.

My django project has two apps - blog and weather, each with a model.

blog.models

```
import datetime
from django.db import models

class BlogEntry(models.Model):
    
    date = models.DateField('Date')
    blog_name = models.CharField('Name',max_length = 255, null=True)
```

weather.models

```
import datetime
from django.db import models

class WeatherEntry(models.Model):
        
    date = models.DateField('Date')
    weather = models.CharField('Weather',max_length = 255, null=True)
```

The weather app is meant to be filled in once daily, but the blog app is only to be filled in occasionally. Now, I want to produce a DetailView for my BlogEntry model which would also show the weather on the day the blog was created. My plan was to override `get_context_data()` but I could not filter the Weather queryset according to the date.

In the view

```
import datetime
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from blog.models import BlogEntry
from weather.models import WeatherEntry


class BlogDetailView(DetailView):
    model = BlogEntry
    template_name = 'Blog/blog_detail.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['weather'] = WeatherEntry.objects.filter(date__=date)
    return context
```

I would get the error `NameError: name 'date' is not defined`. I've using F expressions too and they didn't work either :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is clear. You have no date variable defined. That is because no date varible defined or passed to `get_context_data` method. First, you have to make sure, date variable defined or already passed to `get_context_data` method. Second, fix your indentation method. Indentation in python is matters. It should be like this

```
class BlogDetailView(DetailView):
    model = BlogEntry
    template_name = 'Blog/blog_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['weather'] = WeatherEntry.objects.filter(date=self.object.date)
        return context
```

Comment: Thank you. How should I define the date variable to achieve my objectives? Yes I apologise for the indentation, it is correct in my code, just a mistake when I copy and pasted it in here.

Comment: Yes I have tried it before and just tried it again. It returns the error 'BlogDetailView' object has no attribute 'date'' when I tried to run the page.

Comment: Let me see your route path url

Comment: path('<slug:slug>/', views.BlogDetailView.as_view(), name="show_entry")
The code I provided above in the main post was simplified for the model fields. Actual code has a slug field consisting of a sluggified date and random strings in the BlogEntry model.  
Page loads fine if I remove the get_context_data method, just won't be able to obtain the weather data. 

Maybe I have to 'link' the weather model to the slug of the BlogEntry model?

Comment: Well. then to get access date field from BlogEntry, call it like this `WeatherEntry.objects.filter(date=self.object.date)`. I updated the answer.